# examination problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, nilpotence

let N be a non-zero 3 x 3 matrix with property $N^2 = 0 $ , then show that N has one non-zero eigen vector ., ,..,.,.,.,.,., accumulating all the the knowledge that i have about linear algebra , the question still seems too general for me to reach relevant approach .

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $N$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $N^2$, hence $\lambda^2=0$ and therfore $\lambda=0$.

Thus, the only possible eigenvalue of $N$ is $0$.

Since $N \ne 0$, there is $x \ne 0$ with $y:=Nx \ne 0$.

Result: $Ny=N^2x=0$

Comment: but what is the guarantee that the  ' 0 ' eigen value has geometric multiplicity 1 , it might have geometric multiplicity 2 or 3 as well

Comment: or in other words 

Since $N \ne 0$, there are many possible $x \ne 0$ with $y:=Nx \ne 0$.
and hence there are may possible y's
 for which 

 $Ny=N^2x=0$

Comment: Yes,  and what is the problem? ?

Comment: well i apologize that i din stated the problem clearly,,, we  need to prove that N  has one and only one linearly independent eigen vector